# BIBO Stability of a piecewise function

Tags: math, stability

I have a function $y$ defined as 
$$
y(t) = 
\left\{\begin{array}
~t~  \mbox{ where} |t| \le 3\\
0~ \mbox{ otherwise}
\end{array}
\right .
$$
 With a system defined as

$$G(t) = ty(t), $$

is it BIBO stable? I know that if my function is defined at all points along the time axis then it will not be stable. But if $t=4, y(t)=0$, would this be considered bounded and thus BIBO stable?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What is $G(t)$? The statement "if my function is defined at all points along the time axis then it will not be stable" is wrong.

Comment: 1. Take definition of BIBO stable from textbook. 2. put in terms you've got. 3. Profit. What exactly do you need help with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll assume that you are referring to an LTI system with impulse response $G(t)$. The system is stable if the impulse response is absolutely integrable:

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}|G(t)| \ \mathrm{d}t<\infty$$

Because $G(t)$ has a closed form, we can actually compute that integral:

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}|G(t)| \ \mathrm{d}t=\int_{-3}^3|t^2| \ \mathrm{d}t=18 <\infty$$

So the system is BIBO stable.